# NFS locking on Windows

Tags: windows, nfs, locking

I'm mapping a network drive on Windows and I would like to make sure that during a copy the files can be deleted / modified by the server.

From the Microsoft documentation it seems that we need to specify when we want to lock a file on the server, is it right ?

Comment: Its lock while a process access them, whats your problem exactly you want to solve ?

Comment: Is really NFS or rather SMB/CIFS?